# setTerminal removes content instead of layout

Tags: zend-framework2

Hi i have a zf2 application.
In my module i attach a listener to the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` event.
In this listener i check if the user is authenticated etc.
If the user is authenticated i change the layout.

Now if i call `$viewModel->setTerminal(true)` in my action no content is shown, just the layout but i need it the other way around.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21441607/1594076
This answer somewhat explains what wrong i think but it's not real clear to me.
Also the solution provided is not working in my situation as i would have to add the 2 methods to all my controllers.

Anybody that has a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout listener you'll need to apply some conditional logic to determine if the view model your controller returned is terminal before setting a layout.

This can be done by getting the result from the `MvcEvent` in your listener and checking it's a `ViewModel` instance that doesn't `terminate()`

```
public function yourLayoutListenerCallback(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // get the dispatched result from the event 
    $result = $e->getResult();
    // check it's a view model that doesn't terminate 
    if (!$result instanceof \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel || $result->terminate()) {
        // do nothing
        return;
    }
    // your existing layout logic ....
}
```

Note: you'll need to make sure your layout listener has a low enough priority (>= -10 seems to be enough) such that your controller action has actually returned the view model before testing the condition.